# jquery get first text element attribute from selected dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

both simple and complicate question:
I have my dropdown item created programmatically from ajax request and that is ok. So i serve name and surname for convenient aestetic way, but i need to send an ajax post with only surname and value is needed for other purposes.

```
$('#dropDocente').append('<option value="'+value.idDocente+'"">' + value.surname   + ' ' + value.name  +'</option>');
```

what i would achieve is:

```
var testd = $("#dropDocente option:selected").text();
console.log("Surname is : "+testd);
desired output == Surname is : Doe
```

so, in other hand, i would like get only first element of text in selected dropbox.

I can help me to understand how to reach my goal?

Comment: Description is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `value.surname` as a `data-surname` data tag onto the option and then retrieve that value by selecting the option and using `.data('surname')`. you can do this for any other value you want to single out as well

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var values = [
    { surname: "Doe", name: "John", idDocente: "some value here" },
    { surname: "Shmo", name: "John", idDocente: "some value here2" },
    { surname: "Little", name: "John", idDocente: "some value here3" },
  ];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  var value = values[i];
    $('#dropDocente').append('<option value="'+value.idDocente+
   '" data-surname="'+ value.surname +'">' + value.surname   + ' ' 
   + value.name  +'</option>');
  }
  
  // default first
  $('.results').text($("#dropDocente option:first").data('surname') + ', ' + $("#dropDocente option:first").val());
  
  // on change, get the surname
  $('#dropDocente').on('change', function() {
    $('.results').text($("#dropDocente option:selected").data('surname')+ ', ' + $("#dropDocente option:selected").val());
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDocente">
</select>
<br/><br/><br/>
<div class="results">
</div>
```

Comment: Indubitable, you R resolved my question in elegant and efficien way! Thank you. Your answer teach to me that is possible to have multiple value.

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, you don't use the .text() method to get the value of a dropdown menu. You need to just have:

```
var testd = $("#dropDocente").val();
```

and that will return the selected option's value from the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You could just split full name on select change.

Something like this:

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    var fullName = $('select option:selected').text();
    var surname = fullName.split(" ", 1);
});
```

Full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/1aj06Lw6/1/

Comment: jakob good job!!! an +1 for you. I was fight to choose accepted answer... At end my preferences was to another answer because now i know more than qustion at all. Thank You  for spending your time. Grazie

Comment: good answer, but for future reference, this will only work if the surname is 1 word, but this answer is totally sufficient for most surnames